# ServerSocketChannel.open() never returned

Tags: java, sockets

Call to ServerSocketChannel.open() never returned. We are using jdk1.8.0_144.

Stack trace revealed that that it stayed in ServerSocketChannelImpl class initialization forever. Probably loading nio or net libraries.

```
Thread 12345: (state = IN_VM)
 - sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.<clinit>() @bci=16, line=356
 - sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.<clinit>() @bci=16, line=439
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openServerSocketChannel() @bci=0, line=56
 - java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel.open() @bci-3, line=108
```

Answer (score 1):

After much debugging and trial its fixed when we upgraded java to **jdk1.8.0_172** version. Either the jdk1.8.0_144 is corrupted or had bug.